# polymorphism in objective-c

Tags: cocoa

In objective-c,whether get & set methods can be used in polymorphism or not?
if yes then please explain how we can implement them ?,& if no then why?

can anyone explain it?

Comment: What so you mean? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

In Objective-C all methods (including getters and setters created by `@synthesize`) behave the same. The method dispatch is always done at runtime (like C++ `virtual` methods or non-`final` methods in Java). There is nothing special to do to enable polymorphism, it’s the default and only way.

I hope this answers your question which is not very clear. Please update your question if that’s not what you wanted.

Comment: I have reverted Georg's edit.  I think it's bad to add information to somebody else's answer rather than put in a comment.  It's especially bad to put in information that is wrong.  I nearly down voted because the addition said something incorrect.